# Why is plot not displayed in the main panel?

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I'm new to R shiny and trying to generate plots in the dashboard. Everything gets displayed but the plots. I do not get errors too. Could anyone say, what exactly I'm doing wrong?

I tried using different options for generating graphs like
ggplot, plotOutput. Neither works.

```
library(shiny) 
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr) 
library(shinydashboard)
data <- read.csv("sample.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput("daterange", "Choose the date",
             start = min(data$YEAR),
             end = max(data$YEAR),
             min = min(data$YEAR),
             max = max(data$YEAR),
             separator = " - ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
             startview = 'Week', language = 'Eng', weekstart = 1),  
  selectInput(inputId = 'Product',
          label='Product',
          choices=c('Product1','Product2'),
          selected='Product1'),
  plotOutput("barplot", height = 500))
server <- function(input, output) {

  a<-reactive({
data <- read.csv("sample.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)
dataset <- subset(data, Date >= input$daterange[1] & Date <= input$daterange[2])
dataset = switch(input$Product,
                 "Product1" = Product1,
                 "Product2" = Product2)  
dataset
})

output$barplot <-renderPlot({
color<- c("blue", "green")
barplot(data$PRODUCT, data$VALUE,
col = color)
})

}
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get no errors.

Comment: Seems like you have a typo in your `barplot` call. Should it be `barplot(data$PRODUCT, data$VALUE, col=color)`?

Comment: Thanks @teofil. I just noticed it and corrected. But the plot still doesn't show up.

Comment: Should `barplot` call the variables from the `dateRangeInput()` reactive? Include a `cat(nrow(dateRangeInput()))` inside `renderPlot` (maybe) to check whether the returned object (dataset) is what you want.

Comment: It'd be much easier to help if you included some real or made up data. Otherwise can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, I need the barplot to call variables from sample.csv. Hence, I have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: In that case, a minimal reproducible example would only require (1) reading the data outside the app, (2) the `plotOutput` call in `ui` and (3) the `renderPlot` call in `server`. Everything else is obsolete, including loading libraries other than `shiny`. See if your code works with this minimal example? If not, provide some data to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `barplot(a()$PRODUCT, a()$VALUE)` instead of `data`?